# How to save every predicted result in each iteration of GridSearchCV with LightGBM

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search, lightgbm, gridsearchcv

I am trying to use GridSearchCV to tune parameters in LightGBM model, but I am not familiar enough with how to save each predicted result in each iteration of GridSearchCV.
But sadly, I only know how to save the result in a specific parameter.
Here is the code:

```
param = {
    'bagging_freq': 5,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.4,
    'boost_from_average':'false',
    'boost': 'gbdt',
    'feature_fraction': 0.05,
    'learning_rate': 0.01,
    'max_depth': -1,  
    'metric':'auc',
    'min_data_in_leaf': 80,
    'min_sum_hessian_in_leaf': 10.0,
    'num_leaves': 13,
    'num_threads': 8,
    'tree_learner': 'serial',
    'objective': 'binary', 
    'verbosity': 1
}
features = [c for c in train_df.columns if c not in ['ID_code', 'target']]
target = train_df['target']
folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=44000)
oof = np.zeros(len(train_df))
predictions = np.zeros(len(test_df))

for fold_, (trn_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(folds.split(train_df.values, target.values)):
    print("Fold {}".format(fold_))
    trn_data = lgb.Dataset(train_df.iloc[trn_idx][features], label=target.iloc[trn_idx])
    val_data = lgb.Dataset(train_df.iloc[val_idx][features], label=target.iloc[val_idx])    
    num_round = 1000000
    clf = lgb.train(param, trn_data, num_round, valid_sets = [trn_data, val_data], verbose_eval=1000, early_stopping_rounds = 3000)
    oof[val_idx] = clf.predict(train_df.iloc[val_idx][features], num_iteration=clf.best_iteration)        
    predictions += clf.predict(test_df[features], num_iteration=clf.best_iteration) / folds.n_splits

print("CV score: {:<8.5f}".format(roc_auc_score(target, oof)))
print('Saving the Result File')
res= pd.DataFrame({"ID_code": test.ID_code.values})
res["target"] = predictions
res.to_csv('result_10fold{}.csv'.format(num_sub), index=False)
```

Here is the data:

```
train_df.head(3)

         ID_code    target    var_0    var_1    ...  var_199
0        train_0     0        8.9255   -6.7863       -9.2834     
1        train_1     1        11.5006  -4.1473        7.0433  
2        train_2     0        8.6093   -2.7457       -9.0837 


train_df.head(3)

         ID_code    var_0   var_1    ... var_199
0        test_0     9.4292  11.4327      -2.3805          
1        test_1     5.0930  11.4607      -9.2834      
2        train_2    7.8928  10.5825      -9.0837
```

I want to save each `predictions` of each iteration of GridSearchCV and I have searched several similar questions and some other relevant information of using **GridSearchCV in LightGBM**.
BUT I still can't code it right.
SO, if not mind, could anyone help me and give some tutorials about it?
Thanks sincerely.

Comment: There is  a small issue, because you are currently referring to `GridSearchCV`, which requires a model, that comply with sklearn model training API. However, you use the native lightgbm training API. The two do not work together. If you want to use `GridSearchCV`, then you'll have to use the sklearn API of lightgbm (`lgb.LGBMClassifier`). However, I do not thnk that you want `GridSearchCV` at all. Instead you should wrap you main loop into another one, in which you will loop over parameters. You can get parameters generated analogous to grid search using `sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid`

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi Thanks for your help. I have tried a lot way, but most of them couldn't meet my requirement. So, I just wrapped the loop into a function and save all different parameters into a `param_list` whose type is a dictionary. But I still think this is an ugly way if you mind could you give me some advice on [the code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tCfkqVWrKQ/). Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ParameterGrid` or `ParameterSampler` from sklearn to do parameter sampling- it will correspond to the `GridSearchCV` and `RandomSearchCV`, respectively. For example,

```py
def train_lgb(num_folds=11, param=param_original):
    ...
    return predictions, sub

params = {
# your base parameters
}

# define the grid for parameter sampling
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
par_grid = ParameterGrid([{'bagging_freq':[6,7]},
                          {'num_leaves': [13,15]}
                         ])

prediction_list = {}
sub_list = {}

import copy
for i, ps in enumerate(par_grid):
    print('This is param{}'.format(i))
    # copy the base params dictionary and update with sampled values
    val = copy.deepcopy(params)
    val.update(ps)
    # main training loop
    prediction, sub = train_lgb(param=val) 
    prediction_list.update({key: prediction})
    sub_list.update({key: sub})
```

Edit: By the way, I realized that i was investigating the same issue recently and was learning how to address using some ML tools. I've created a page summarising how to use [MLflow](http://mlflow.org) for this task: https://mlisovyi.github.io/KaggleSantander2019/ (and the associated github page for the actual code). Note, that it by accident is based on the same data that you are working on :). I hope it will be useful.